# QED breaking of parity invariance

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, symmetry-breaking, parity

QED is invariant under P,T,C for the Lagrangian containing operators of dimension equal or smaller than 4. I was wondering, what are the possible parity-breaking terms in QED with dimension smaller or equal than 6?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to physics stackexchange! What have you tried yourself to answer this question? Is there anything specific you have trouble with? (e.g. how P acts on the various fields available, or how to work out how it acts on composite operators?)

Comment: Thanks man! I figured out that I need the gamma matrices contracted in some way, and I managed to find some options, but I wanted to double-check.

Comment: How does the reader check your good faith options without seeing them?